# In Python, how do you import objects without executing the other code?

Tags: python, module

For example take a.py

```
stringcheese = "hi"
print("I don't want this printed")
```

and now b.py:

```
from a import stringcheese
print(stringcheese)
```

The output is:

```
I don't want this printed
hi
```

How can I just import `stringcheese` without executing `a.py`'s code?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The top-level code for a module *must* be executed for the module to load in the first place.

Only put executable statements in the top-level of your module that you are fine with being executed on import.

Comment: Sorry, what does top level mean?

Comment: @POSUMSHREDER: Any module code outside of functions (the function objects are created, but their code isn't executed until you call the function).

Answer (score -1):

POSUM SHREDER, you can use `if __name__ == '__main__'` construction to hide unwated executables from import, they still wll be executed if you call `python a.py`.

a.py

```
stringcheese = "hi"
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print("I don't want this printed")
```

main.py

```
from a import stringcheese
print(stringcheese)
```

for more details please read [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Your answer is right but explain your answer a little don't just dump code, so others and the OP can learn

Comment: @Trigremm Your answer could still use more love, such as quickly explaining what `__name__` is in addition to the link. I'm +1-ing your answer for the editing effort though, it's a significant improvement over your initial version. Welcome to Stack Overflow.